# Javascript promise : is there any differences between anonymous and not anonymous callbacks?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
const example = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve();
    console.log('1');
} )

example().then(console.log('3'))
console.log('2');
```

prints out 1 3 2

```
function create() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve();
        console.log('1');
    });
};

create().then(function() {
    console.log('3');
}, function() {
    console.log('4');
});

console.log('2');
```

prints out 1 2 3

I tested more than ten times each. But results are same.
why this difference occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, not a function call such as `console.log` (which doesn't return a function, but returns `undefined`). So when you do

`example().then(console.log('3'))`

upon encountering the `.then`, it immediately evaluates `console.log('3')`, with the interpreter hoping/expecting for the function call to return a *function*, so that it can put the returned function into the `.then` chain. So, the `console.log('3')` gets printed immediately. But `console.log` returns *undefined* - it's *not* a function that goes into the asynchronous `.then` chain.

It doesn't actually have anything to do with named vs anonymous functions. Your first snippet gives the `.then` a *function* as a parameter, but the second snippet gives the `.then` a `console.log` call as a parameter (which is evaluated immediately and returns undefined).

Just by adding `() =>` before the first snippet's `console.log`, you'll see that it behaves identically to the second snippet, by making the `console.log` call run asynchronously after the main thread is finished:

```js
const example = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    resolve();
    console.log('1');
} )

example().then(() => console.log('3'))
console.log('2');
```